# Swift: How to reload new content (eg. array) every time the tableview appears?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview

I am having a tab bar with two views:

- tablview
- view controller to add data

Then I am having an array, which will be updated from the view controller with new content (eg. just append new strings).

This array populates the table view.
Now when the app starts the table view shows all the arrays content, but when I move via the tab bar to the view controller, add content to the array and move back via tab bar to the tableview, I am not able to update the tableview so that it pulls the new content from the array.

I tried to use `tableview.reloadData()` in both `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad`, but the tableview doesn't reload and still shows the data it has initially loaded at the app start, but not the new content.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        weightArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "favorites") as! [String]
    }
```

This is how I populate the tableview:

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return weightArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "FavoriteCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        let weights = weightArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = weights

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: try `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: you can use the `didSet` property observer of your datasource to reload your `tableView` but in your case there could be an additional catch here. How do you update the datasource in the other `ViewController`? Swift `Array`s are `struct`s so they are value type. If you update the array, it has to be mapped back. Now depending on your design, we'll see what needs to be done. So share code pertaining to this.

Comment: `viewWillAppear()` works, but only after not immediately after adding content to the array. Basically the tableview has to appear twice to reload everything. - I have added the tableview data source code.

Comment: tab bar did not load viewController again, thats why viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear is  not working.

Comment: You should always call super's viewWillAppear.  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
        weightArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "favorites") as! [String]
    }

Comment: Also show the viewController class declaration.

Comment: @RjC isn't your call to reload before setting the array?

Comment: Cheers @staticVoidMan I was in a rush trying viewWillAppear() and didn't realize out the reload before the array. Thanks!

Comment: @RjC Happens :D Anyways, I've updated my answer. You can either delete your question or accept my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `reloadData()` call is before updating array.

It should be after updating the datasource:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    weightArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "favorites") as! [String]
    tableView.reloadData()    
}
```

---

Anyways, you can make use of the `didSet` property observer of your datasource object.

```
//your weightArray declaration
var weightArray = [String]() {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

and then you can do:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    weightArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "favorites") as! [String]   
}
```

This way, anytime you change the array, your `tableView` will reload.