# Refresh or reload data in function ViewWillAppear not always working in UITableViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I set one UITabbarViewController as first view of my app, and UITableViewcontroller is one tab, this tableview will show some transaction data get from URL response data.

What I did is I defined one array as member of tableviewcontroller, then in Viewwillappear the array data was refreshed everytime, the expected result will be: whenever I tap the tableview tab, the data will reload or refresh again.

Now the problem is sometimes it working perfectly, but sometimes it showing blank tableview

I tried google the similar problem in stackoverflow and found similar question, but the provided solution not working for me. For example below

[Swift: How to reload new content (eg. array) every time the tableview appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060572/swift-how-to-reload-new-content-eg-array-every-time-the-tableview-appears)

below is my code:

```
class TransactionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var transactionList = [transactionDetail]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.dataSource=self
    self.tableView.delegate=self
}


 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //every tap, trigger reload
    reloadTransaction()
    //refresh table view
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


internal func reloadTransaction(){
    self.transactionList.removeAll()

    //get URL response and append data to transactinList
    ....
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return transactionList.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //if transactionList.count>0 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TransactionTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as!
        TransactionTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.scanTime.text=transactionList[indexPath.row].scanTime
    cell.productName.text=transactionList[indexPath.row].productName
    cell.productID.text=transactionList[indexPath.row].productID
    cell.location.text=transactionList[indexPath.row].location

    return cell
    //}
}
```

is there anything I missing? I expect the data should be always correct

Comment: You must reload your table view inside your "reloadTransaction()" method & not in viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you should consider. First reload data will be called right away after reloadTransaction() if your url request hasn't processed yet, it will show an empty tableView.

Second, when you have new data make sure to call the main thread before you call self.tableView.reloadData():

```
internal func reloadTransaction(){
    self.transactionList.removeAll()

    //get URL response and append data to transactinList
    ....
    //call self.tableView.reloadData() here after you append the new data

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  when I put the tableview.reloaddata inside reloadtransaction function, it works perfectly! Addtionally question is , seems I still put it reloaddata into main thread, is there some best practice or apple document for this?

Comment: You're welcome. UI updates / changes should always be done in the main thread. Because reload data, redraws the tableview and the cells. It should be called on the main thread.